# @fontface fonts do not render

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the `@fontface` syntax for using extra fonts on my webpage. The thing is that while fonts appear as they should in dreamweaver, when I preview the page in Firefox or IE fonts do not render.

Here is the syntax I use:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KomikaTextRegular';
    src: url('/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.svg#KomikaTextRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 1024px;
    font-family: 'KomikaTextRegular', DeliciousRoman, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: If you open Firebug in FF or developer toolbar in IE, is the font downloaded as a resource in the network tab ?

Comment: Where are you loading the fonts? Locally in a page or on a webserver?

Comment: Both. I test it locally & in a test server. But in both it doesn't work. I tried the full path on the server /www/demo.site.com/fonts/ but still nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the full url , with the servername too?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'KomikaTextRegular';
src: url('Http://servername/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.eot');
src: url('Http://servername/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('Http://servername/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('Http://servername/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('Http://servername/fonts/KOMTXT__-webfont.svg#KomikaTextRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Or without  ''?

```
body { margin:0;
        min-width:1024px;  
        font-family: KomikaTextRegular, DeliciousRoman, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
    }
```

Also [it's](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) it a good article about using of the  font-face.

Comment: i tried different syntaxes includes the one you propose but they don't work.

Comment: i m using FF 8.0.1 and ie 8 . i tried as u said the full path but still nothing

Comment: Can you see this font in firebug?

Comment: it seems to work now on the test server. I actually did nothing. Tested some different syntaxes but when i returned to my first syntax it worked. Weird! Thanks for your help & interest anyway

Answer (score 0):

If your full path is `/www/demo.site.com/fonts/`

and you use `/fonts` it may jump back to look for it in `/www/fonts/` rather than the folder you want. Depends on what the root folder is set to really. Try base href maybe?

What if you take the first `/` off, does that work?

Try inspect it in firebug and find out where the path is to the css files.